# enumitem: referencing items in enumerate

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, enumitem, cleveref

Say we have a huge document with many `sections`, `subsections`, and `subsubsections`.  In a few of these sections, we have `enumerate`d environments.

The package I am using is `enumitem`.

One of the environments could look like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{one}
  \item
\end{enumerate}
referring back to \cref{one}
```

Now if I reference this item later, it will say:

> referring back to `item 1`

I could have other enumerated environments with `\alph`, `(\alph)`, etc. and there reference could be `item (a)` or something.

The problem I have is what if I have another environment with the standard numbers that starts from 1 and goes to 4 but item 1 is also labeled.
I would have another `item 1` reference in the document.  The `hyperref` would take it to a different list but is there a way to differentiate the printed out reference?

The list are unrelated so I don't want to start the new environment continuing the old numbering. Say starting from 3 and so on.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    one \label{one}
  \item
    two \label{two}
\end{enumerate}
This \cref{two} is great.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    one \label{dog}
  \item
    two \label{cat}
\end{enumerate}
This \cref{cat} is a cat.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Would there be a way to change one of the references to `observation 1` instead of `item 1`?  This would be a local change nor global.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would consider defining a new list

```
\newlist{observations}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[observations]{label*=\arabic*}
```

and then tweaking `crefname` accordingly

```
\crefname{observationsi}{observation}{obvservations}
\Crefname{observationsi}{Observation}{Obvservations}
```

Here's the output

[image: screenshot]

and a complete MWE to play with

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newlist{observations}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[observations]{label*=\arabic*}

\crefname{observationsi}{observation}{obvservations}
\Crefname{observationsi}{Observation}{Obvservations}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    one \label{one}
  \item
    two \label{two}
\end{enumerate}
This \cref{two} is great.
\begin{observations}
  \item one \label{dog}
  \item two \label{cat}
\end{observations}
This \cref{cat} is a cat.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the observations in the output lack a dot after the number. To fix that, use `\setlist[observations]{label*=\arabic{*}.}`

Comment: Great. Feel free to edit :)

Comment: Should we use `~` before `\cref{cat}`? Why do we use `obvservations ` instead of `observations `?

Comment: @alper feel free to edit

Answer (score 15):

Use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `label` and `ref` keys to yield a different printed label for each item or reference text when using `\ref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,cleveref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    one \label{one}
  \item
    two \label{two}
\end{enumerate}
This \cref{two} is great.
\begin{enumerate}[ref={observation~\arabic*}]
  \item
    one \label{dog}
  \item
    two \label{cat}
\end{enumerate}
This \ref{cat} is a cat.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know of any possible conflicts?  I used this procedure and it printed out `item observation 2`.

Comment: @dustin: Note that I'm using `\ref` and not `\cref`.

Comment: How can we get `\cref` to work `enumitem`?

Comment: @dustin: [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) provides `\labelcref` which does the same as `\ref`. Are you after using a regular `\cref` that produces `item X` in one instance, but `observation Y` in another?

Comment: I dont quite understand your question but cmhughes was able to solve the problem by creating a new list.

Comment: See also: [How can I get cleveref / enumitem to print, not 'item (e)', but 'Proposition 1 (e)'?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156049/5645)

Comment: Related, please help! https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470579/41144

Comment: I believe this works without the `enumitem` package too.

Comment: @young_souvlaki: Provide code that you believe works; I've not seen an adaptation of `enumerate` to accommodate optional arguments and provide similar functionality to [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).