# How can I get cleveref / enumitem to print, not 'item (e)', but 'Proposition 1 (e)'?

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumitem, cleveref

I currently make use of `enumitem` and `cleveref` to show references to theorems. Sometimes, I want to reference a point in a list inside of a theorem. It should show `[Name of theorem type, e.g. Propsiton] [Number] [number inside list]`, but it shows `item [number inside list]`

How can I get this?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} % needed for math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[german,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\newframedtheorem{satz}{Satz}[section]
\newframedtheorem{proposition}[satz]{Proposition}
\crefname{proposition}{Proposition}{Propositionen}
\begin{document}
\section{adfa}
adsfasdfasdf asdf asdf asd fasdfasd asd fasdf asdf
asdfasdfa sasdfas dfasdf asdf

\begin{proposition}\leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), ref=\theenumi{} (\alph*)]
        \item asdfasdf asdf asdf sdf
        \item  sdfas dasdfasd fasdf asdf asdf 
        \item asdfasd asdf asdf sad f
        \item \label{prop:15.2d} a fa ssd fas df
        \item \label{prop:15.2e} sdf asd asdf sad f
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proposition}

As shown in \cref{prop:15.2d} ...
\end{document}
```

### Rendered

[image]

"Punkt" is German for "item".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to (a) instructing LaTeX to prepend the `proposition number` to the `level-one item number` when creating cross-references, say, via an instruction such as

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), ref=\theproposition~(\alph*)]
```

when starting the enumerated list, you also need to (b) use the `\crefalias` command to inform `cleveref` that entities of type `enumi` (first-level enumerated items) should be referred to as propositions; by default, `cleveref` will refer to them as items (or "Punkte" in German):

```
\crefalias{enumi}{proposition}
```

If the *only* instances of enumerated lists in your document are inside `proposition` environments, these are the only two modifications you should need to make in order to achieve your cross-referencing objective. However, this simple solution is probably too far-reaching since it applies to *all* cross-references to `enumi` entities, not just those contained inside proposition environments.

Fortunately, the `enumitem` package provides a convenient method for creating new enumerated lists with associated dedicated counters. For instance, you could add the instructions

```
\newlist{propenum}{enumerate}{1} % also creates a counter called 'propenumi'
\setlist[propenum]{label=\alph*), ref=\theproposition~(\alph*)}
\crefalias{propenumi}{proposition}
```

in the preamble, after `enumitem` and `cleveref` have been loaded. Then, use the `propenum` environment to create enumerated lists inside `proposition` environments:

```
\begin{proposition}\leavevmode
\begin{propenum} % use 'propenum', not 'enumerate'
        \item asdfasdf asdf asdf sdf
        \item  sdfas dasdfasd fasdf asdf asdf 
        \item asdfasd asdf asdf sad f
        \item \label{prop:15.2d} a fa ssd fas df
        \item \label{prop:15.2e} sdf asd asdf sad f
\end{propenum}
\end{proposition}
```

With this setup, the instruction

```
As shown in \cref{prop:15.2d} \dots
```

will generate this output:

[image]

`\cref`-based cross-references to "ordinary" level-one `enumerate`-environments items will continue to show up as "Punkt xx" (or as "item xx" if the german language options aren't set...).

*Addendum*: In your follow-up comments you mention that you'd like to embed these cross-references inside math mode and would like to avoid seing the string "Proposition" (or "Propositionen") be rendered in math-italic mode -- without having to encase the `\cref` instructions in explicit `\text` or `\textup` commands. To achieve this additional objective, you could provide the following commands in the preamble:

```
\crefname{proposition}{\textup{Proposition}}{\textup{Propositionen}}
\setlist[propenum]{label=\alph*), ref=\textup{\theproposition~(\alph*)}}
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer- in my early tests I thought it was `babel` giving the `Punk't` word (I didn't know if this was German for Proposition). Anyway, +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I use $\xRightarrow{\cref{prop:15.2d}}$ it will make the text italic. Should I use it like `$\xRightarrow{\text{\cref{prop:15.2d}}}$` or is there a possiblity to get it automatically always in text mode?

Comment: I'd try `ref=\textup{\theproposition~(\alph*)}` (in the definition of the `propenum` environment) first.

Comment: `\textup` does not work.

Comment: @moose - By "does not work", do you mean that the string "Proposition" is set in math-italics? If so, I guess you could also write `\crefname{proposition}{\textup{Proposition}}{\textup{Propositionen}}` to force these strings to be set in upright roman mode. If you have two arguments in the `\cref` instruction while in math mode, you may also need `\renewcommand\crefpairconjunction{\textup{ und}}`. And, if you have multiple `\cref` arguments, you will also need to redefine `\crefmiddleconjunction` and `\creflastconjuntion`...

Comment: @Mico: Thanks (+1), putting the content of `\crefname` worked (by "works" I mean that it is not not put in italics in math mode).

Comment: @moose - Glad it's working for you now. I've added some information in the body of the answer about ensuring that the font used for the cross-reference is upright-roman.