# How to Link Problems and Solutions

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, enumitem

I'm writing a book containing problems in some topics of mathematics. I've done writing the problem and the solution using `enumerate` environment. But now I want to link the solution to the problem using `hyperref`. At first I change them manually, but it seems like there are too many of them.

Some solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45428. Is there a way so that I don't have to start over?  [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You just want to include a link from each question to the solution, and both are written in enumerate? There are questions on referencing items in a list, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128607/117534. If otherwise, it is typically good practice to provide a minimal working example (`\documentclass`, relevant packages, and `\begin{document}/\end{document}`  commands) that reproduces your issue.