# Enumerate: reference and hyperlink /hyperref the "numbering" of items

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem, hyperlink

I aim to use

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
...
    \end{enumerate}
```

> *Goal*: such that the numbering (1,2,3,...) of each item in the list can have a  reference and hyperlink /hyperref, so I can refer to them later. **How to do it?** Thank you in advance.

Presumably, I need to add

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

> How to reference and hyperlink /hyperref the "numbering" of items, presumably with a blue color for each number (1,2,3,...)?

A minimal MWE follows a related post here [enumitem: referencing items in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128605/41144) from @Werner
is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,cleveref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    one \label{one}
  \item
    two \label{two}
\end{enumerate}
This \cref{two} is great.
\begin{enumerate}[ref={observation~\arabic*}]
  \item
    one \label{dog}
  \item
    two \label{cat}
\end{enumerate}
This \ref{cat} is a cat.
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to reference them `\item`s? Use `\label` and then you can `\ref` later. Oh, that's what you're already doing. So, what's the question?

Comment: What's the question here? Loading `hyperref` helps

Comment: Does \hyperref give a hyperlink? I am not sure

Comment: I want to have the \itme number in blur color, and it can be referred later with a hyperref or hyperlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're interested in the following; setting the `label` to use a colour and using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s `linkcolor` to make it match:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor = blue
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textcolor{blue}{\arabic*.}, ref=\arabic*]
  \item
    one \label{one}
  \item
    two \label{two}
\end{enumerate}

This \cref{two} is great.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks +1, this is basically what I wanted

Comment: The key is this "[label=\textcolor{blue}{\arabic*.}, ref=\arabic*]" I do not know this before!

Comment: @wonderich: Indeed. You can specify a separate `label` and `ref` key. The former will be used for printing the `\item` number and the latter will be used if you `\ref` a `\label` set in that `\item`.

Comment: You have comments on this too? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470600/41144 Thank you!