# How can I apply ref to items with numbers

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I am using `enumitem` by using them as numbers. If possible I want to site items by their numbers. For example, In the following code wanted behaviour is "This step `4.1` is great" , where I don't get any item number at all.

code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelwidth=!,itemindent=!,labelindent=0pt,label*=\arabic*.]
    \item[(1)]
        one \label{one}
    \item[(2)]
        two \label{two}
    \item[(3)]
        three \label{three}
    \item[(4)]
        four \label{four}
    \item[(4.1)]
        fourone \label{fourone}
\end{enumerate}

This step~\ref{fourone} is great.  % I want to get: This step 4.1] is great.
This step~\cref{fourone} is great.  % I want to get: This step 4.1 is great.

\end{document}
```

Base code is taken from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128608/127048

Comment: why are you numbering by hand, the whole point of `enumerate` is to auto-number, if you remove the `[..]` then `\label` will work

Comment: In my answer I assumed the bracket in  "I want to get: This step 4.1] is great." was a typo, but if you really want the closing bracket after 4.1, I can change my answer.

Comment: `\label` uses macros (like `\@currentlabel`) which are set by `\refstepcounter`.  However, `\item[]` does not call `\refstepcounter`.

Comment: I am using enumitem by using them as numbers. If possible I want to **site** items by their numbers. For example, In the following code wanted **behaviour** is "This step 4.1 is great" , where I don't get any item number at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah you are correct, I number the by hand ; I was not able to make it work for numbering inner items automatically for inner items as well, it was doing `a)` instead of `4.1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need manual enumeration, it shouldn't be hard to achieve the kind of thing you want. Here's a first approximation.

(If you have other styles of lists, you might just want to put the options in `[...]` after the `\begin{enumerate}`s rather than use `\setlist`. But `\setlist` is probably easier if you want them all this style.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\setlist[1]{wide, labelwidth=!,itemindent=!,labelindent=0pt,label=(\arabic*),ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[2]{wide, labelwidth=!,itemindent=!,labelindent=0pt,label=(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*),ref=\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*}

\crefname{enumi}{}{}
\crefname{enumii}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        one \label{one}
    \item
        two \label{two}
    \item
        three \label{three}
    \item
        four \label{four}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        fourone \label{fourone}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

This step~\ref{fourone} is great.  % I want to get: This step 4.1 is great.
This step~\cref{fourone} is great.  % I want to get: This step 4.1 is great.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my document there are other items without number `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` could they be remain unaffected?

Comment: Can I try something as follows: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/8fd96a0ebd03fce05b19a71f8c5b18b0 just to label different name for it

Comment: @alper You can use `\setlist[enumerate,1]{...` and `\setlist[enumerate,2]{..` instead of bare `\setlist` to not affect `\itemize`. Or you can mostly do what's at that link with `\setlist[observations,2]{...` and `\setlist[observations,2]{...` and do both `\crefname{observationsi}...` and `\crefname{observationsii}` (and `\Cref` as well).

Comment: Thanks for your commend. I have tried with : `\setlist[observations,1]{` ... `\setlist[observations,2]{..`  // I have also added: `\crefname{observationsi}{}{}
\Crefname{observationsii}{}{}
` seems like it worked. I did not understand which line for `\Cref` should I change as well?

Comment: I was suggesting you have four lines `\crefname{observationsi}{}{}`, `\crefname{observationsii}{}{}`, `\Crefname{observationsi}{}{}` and `\Crefname{observationsii}{}{}`, at least if you plan on using `\cref` and `\Cref` with both.